# XDocument from string has one element, need toDictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xmlString that I am parsing to an XDocument:

```
xmlString = 
"<TestXml>" +
   "<Data>" +
      "<leadData>" +
        "<Email>testEmail@yahoo.ca</Email>" +
        "<FirstName>John</FirstName>" +
        "<LastName>Doe</LastName>" +
        "<Phone>555-555-5555</Phone>" +
        "<AddressLine1>123 Fake St</AddressLine1>" +
        "<AddressLine2></AddressLine2>" +
        "<City>Metropolis</City>" +
        "<State>DC</State>" +
        "<Zip>20016</Zip>" +
     "</leadData>" +
  "</Data>" +
"</TestXml>"
```

I parse the string to an XDocument, and then try and iterate through the nodes:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
Dictionary<string, string> xDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//Convert xDocument to Dictionary
foreach (var child in xDoc.Root.Elements())
{
      //xDict.Add();
}
```

This will only iterate once, and the one iteration seems to have all of the data in it. I realize I am doing something wrong, but after googling around I have no idea what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xDoc.Root.Descendants()` instead of `xDoc.Root.Elements()` in your foreach loop.

Comment: I think this was it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Blankdud No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your *root* has only one child *Data*, therefore it iterates only once

```
var xDict = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
            .Descendants("leadData")
            .Elements()
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);
```

Comment: This seems to return an empty dictionary.

Comment: @Blankdud The only camelCase tag is `leadData`. I think you used `LeadData` in your query. Xml is case sensitive. (Or your xml you used is different).

Comment: The XML I used is a bit different yes, as it contains sensitive data. However, I was using `leadData`.